# How to stream a raw h.264 video in jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming, h.264, jplayer

jplayer supports mp4. But, I have a server that streams a raw h.264 video. Is it possible to stream it directly on the client side using jPlayer? If yes, please tell me how I should do it.
If no, how do I put the video into an mp4 container?

Or, is there any other JS library or jQuery plugin that can be used to display the h.264 stream?

Answer (score 0):

You be better off putting your video file into a container.
If your video stream is already recorded then mp4 is a good choice.
You can wrap your video stream using ffmpeg or may be mp4box.
For playback in the browser you can use the html video tag or your jPlayer.

If you are live streaming - wrap your stream into mpeg dash and use Dash JS for playback.

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample how to generate MPEG-DASH content using open source tools like x264 or MP4Box: http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/